# How do I make an ImageButton to randomly be positioned within a linear layout? (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-imagebutton

I have a linear layout with a certain amount of padding. I want an image button to be placed randomly anywhere within that linear layout without going outside the layout. Here is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="45dp"
    android:text="Text 1"
    android:id="@+id/text1" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:text="Text 2"
    android:id="@+id/text2" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lay1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ib"
    android:id="@+id/button1"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want the ImageButton `button1` to be placed randomly within layout `lay1`.

I have tried getting the width and height of the layout and feeding them into a random function which I then use to provide a left margin and top margin to the imagebutton, but my app keeps crashing whenever I do that. Here's the Java code:

```
ImageButton b = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay1);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) b.getLayoutParams();
int width = l.getWidth();
int height= l.getHeight();
params.leftMargin = new Random().nextInt(width);
params.topMargin = new Random().nextInt(height);
b.setLayoutParams(params);
```

The above method did not work and my app always crashes when I open this activity. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: What do you mean by random? Is it random as in "anywhere on the screen" or is it random as in "One of n possible positions"?

Comment: Wait for answer. I`ll try it.

Comment: do you already have a width and height? could you check if you get 0 there?
If so, you need to add a ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener

Comment: You can do it using `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a partial solution for you.
The following code places a button at a random location **BUT** it can be put off screen. You should be able to prevent this by playing around with the random generator.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

int width, height;
LinearLayout linearLayout;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
    linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            Log.v(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onGlobalLayout");
            width = linearLayout.getWidth();
            height = linearLayout.getHeight();

            placeButton();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        }
    });

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
}

private void placeButton() {
    Log.v(getClass().getSimpleName(), "width: " + width + " Height: " + height);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams();

    Random rand = new Random();

    params.leftMargin = rand.nextInt(width);
    params.topMargin = rand.nextInt(height);

    Log.v(getClass().getSimpleName(), "left: " + params.leftMargin + " top: " + params.topMargin);
    button.setLayoutParams(params);
    button.invalidate();
}
```

}

You just wait for your linearlayout to be drawn. Then you get it's width and height and put the button on a random place.

**Note**
This will move the button around when you rotate the screen. you could prevent this by only adding an `OnGlobalLayoutListener` if `savedInstanceState == null`

Answer (score 1):

Your method looks good, but you also have to take into account the image size.
So I'd put something like :

```
params.leftMargin = new Random().nextInt(width - b.getWidth());
params.topMargin = new Random().nextInt(height - b.getHeight());
```

Now you're gonna have to be more specific about the crash you're experiencing.

EDIT : Also SnyersK is right, if you're going through that piece of code before the element got their dimensions, then you'll need to use a ViewTreeObserver.

Comment: Can you please give me the exact code as to how I can use the ViewTreeObserver? I have tried to use it but it didn't really work for me, I'm not familiar with how a ViewTreeObserver works, so I can't really fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your code with this

```
ImageButton b = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay1);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)l.getLayoutParams();
int width = l.getWidth();
int height= l.getHeight();
params.leftMargin = new Random().nextInt(width);
params.topMargin = new Random().nextInt(height);
l.setLayoutParams(params);
```